# How to solve the issue faced during running command pip install google-colab?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory, metadata, anaconda3, nomodule

I am facing issue while using command from google.colab import drive in anaconda juypter notebook. It shows an error that no module found error. I am attaching the screenshot for your reference too.

```
[Anaconda prompt error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRviE.jpg)
```